# How to get the payload and document id from snapshotChanges in angular 6?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular6

I have below code snippet which does not work in angular 6.The compiler shows error as "Property 'map' does not exist on type '{}'" for the inner map function. Can somebody guide me how to get the payload and id from the snapshot changes .

Code:

```
this.postCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {      //this inner map throws error >Property 'map' does not exist on type '{}'
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
```

dependecies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit with real answer**

I found the issue. You need to declare your postCollection as an AngularFirestoreCollection. Here's how I did it for my code below:

```
    updatedb: AngularFirestoreCollection<item>;
```

Then I could use it without getting the map error. Hope this helps!

**Past (works, but not the best) Answer**

I've been having the same issue. I think it's something to do with your postCollection variable. When I put the full db.collection ... call into there, it worked for me. Not sure if it's something about how that variable is declared (I just had mine as a generic variable, not assigned at the top of the file.

This didn't work:

```
export class DataService {

items$: Observable<any>;
selectedItem$: Observable<any>;
selected3x3: item = new item();
timeout;
email: string;
updatedb;

get3x3s(){
    if(!this.email){
        this.items$ = this.updatedb.snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(changes => {
                return changes.map(doc => {
                    return{
                        id: doc.payload.doc.id,
                        data: doc.payload.doc.data()
                    }
                })
            })
        );
```

But this did compile:

```
export class DataService {

items$: Observable<any>;
selectedItem$: Observable<any>;
selected3x3: item = new item();
timeout;
email: string;
updatedb;

get3x3s(){
    if(!this.email){
        this.items$ = this.db.collection(this.email).snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(changes => {
                return changes.map(doc => {
                    return{
                        id: doc.payload.doc.id,
                        data: doc.payload.doc.data()
                    }
                })
            })
        );
```

Comment: your answer is very useful sir.
i think `.data()` has been deprecated, so I used `doc.payload.val()`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
this.afStore.collection(`${uid}/ingresos-egresos/items`)
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(docData => {
        return docData.map( doc => {
          let data = doc.payload.doc.data() as IngresoEgreso; //here solutions
          return {
            uid: doc.payload.doc.id,
            ...data
          };
        });
      })
    )
    .subscribe(docData => {
      console.log(docData);                  
    });
```